# how to refund money programmatically to user in apple IAP?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Does apple have refund api?

I want to offer my customer a money back policy. If they don't like my services, they can get their money back in period time.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, they don't provide such API.